# Issue in iterating through Request Header in ASP.NET Core (.NET 6)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, http-headers

I am getting an exception intermittently when iterating through Request Headers in my ASP.NET Core API solution.

Code (in Controller)

```
string tenant = GetHeaderValue("x-application");
string environment = GetHeaderValue("x-environment");
string correlationId = GetHeaderValue("x-correlationId");
string transactionId = GetHeaderValue("x-messageId");
string channel = GetHeaderValue("x-channel");

...

protected string GetHeaderValue(string headerKey) 
{
    var headerValues = Request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(header => header.Key.ToLowerInvariant() == headerKey.ToLowerInvariant()); // Exception is being thrown at this line
    return headerValues.Value.FirstOrDefault();

}
```

Exception

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

Comment: Can you share more of the controller code? I usually see this when non-thread safe collections are modified, but that shouldn't happen with headers in a single request.

Comment: @BenMatthews - added more code

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, but may need even more code. What you have there shouldn't even compile I wouldn't think if the Request is being used outside of the controller in another class. Or is this a function within the function? Would perhaps Request.Headers.TryGetValue be better than your own function?

Comment: So `Request.TryGetValue` is working and thats what solved the issue. But i am curious as to what is causing the error if I try to run a FirstOrDefault on the headers collection